# How to validate checkbox form using ajax?

Tags: laravel-5

I have an issue on checkbox ajax validation?

My all other form showing ajax validation except checkbox may be input form has value already but i couldnot figure out solution.

My ajax...

```
    $(function() {


          (function() {

            $('.load').addClass('hide');

            $(document).on('submit', '.add_restaurant', function() {

              // remove prior message which might have accumulated during earlier update
              $('.error-message').each(function() {
                $(this).removeClass('make-visible');
                $(this).html('');
              });


              $('input').each(function() {
                $(this).removeClass('errors');
              });



              // current form under process
              var current_form = $(this);

              // === Dynamically get all the values of input data
              var request_data = {};

              request_data['_token'] = $(this).find('input[name=_token]').val();


              current_form.find('[name]').each(function() {
                request_data[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
              });

              $('.load').addClass('make-visible');
              // == Dynamic value retrieval ends here

              $.post(
                $(this).attr('action'),
                request_data,
                function(data) {

                  console.log(data);

                  if (data.status == 'success') {

                    $('.load').removeClass('hide');

                    console.log('success');


                    if (window.location.href.indexOf("reservation") > -1) {
                      window.location.href = data.url;
                    } else {
                      location.reload();
                    }

                    //location.reload();

                  } else if (data.status == 'fails') {

                    for (var key in data.errors) {

                      // skip loop if the property is from prototype
                      if (!data.errors.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

                      var error_message = data.errors[key];

                      current_form.find("[name=" + key + "]").addClass('errors');

                      var parent = current_form.find("[name=" + key + "]").parent();
                      parent.find('.error-message').addClass('make-visible').html(error_message);

                    }

                  }

                }
              );

          return false;

        });

      })();

});
```

Here is the blade template but i am showing only checkbox form since it is quite long form.

```
<label>Gender</label>
<div class="gender radiobtn">
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="M" id="male">
  <label for="male">Male</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="F" id="female">
  <label for="female">Female</label>
  <span class="error-message"></span>

</div>
```

Where i am wrong?Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks@Ognj3n for formating my code.Will you please help in getting solutiontoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i got answer.What happened was that it already took value so error object wasnot append .

What we need was empty the value and check whether form is checked or not and simply insert in database.

Here how i solve by lots of research

```
        current_form.find('[name]').each(function(){
            request_data[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();


            if($('#male').is(":checked"))
            {
                 request_data['gender']='M';
            }
            if($('#female').is(":checked"))
            {
                request_data['gender']='F';
            }
```

Thank you@Jeric Cruz for valuable suggestion

Answer (score 0):

since you assigned a value on both checkbox, when your validating code run, it is valid. value="M" and value="F"

What you can do is to verify if one of those checkbox is checked or not.

```
current_form.find('[name]').each(function(){
        request_data[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();
    });

if (!$("#male").is(":checked") && !$("#female").is(":checked"))
            {
               //gender has no check
               $(".gender").addClass("errors")
            }
```

if the .is("checked") is not working try to changed it in .attr("checked") == "false"

Comment: Well it didnt work either way.Object error is not shown for checkbox@Jeric Cruz

Comment: Here how i try to manage your code but fails.Could u look on it:@Jeric Cruz

Comment: if (!data.errors.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
                            if ($(this).attr("name") == "gender" && !$(this).attr("checked") == "false") {


                                var error_message = data.errors[key];

                                current_form.find("[name=" + key + "]").addClass('errors');

                                var parent = current_form.find("[name=" + key + "]").parent();
                                parent.find('.error-message').addClass('make-visible').html(error_message);
                            }

Comment: Actually Your code works but i want to append this validation to object error with other field also which isnot happening.How to append?@Jeric Cruz

Comment: kindly check it again

Comment: even though i erase value error is not shown@Jeric Cruz

Comment: well i got concept from you.And manage to solve it .Thanks @Jeric Cruz and i will definitely tick your name as correct answer.